# DNS server at router level vs. computer level

Tags: networking, router, dns

I've three questions.

1. Is it better/faster/optimal to set up your server's preferred and alternate DNS servers in your OS's network settings or in your router settings?
2. Will it cause problems if it is set up in both places, both pointing to the same IPs?
3. I am running Windows and I have my network assign a static IP to one of my computers. This doesn't allow me to obtain the DNS server addresses from my router automatically. Is there an IP I can put in that will cause it to take the DNS server addresses from the router?

Comment: joureyman's answer looks good. re 3, You can perhaps get the dns servers used by your router, from your router's config page. I can on mine.  It   gets them via dhcp from the isp. Alternatively you can tell your individual comp to get dns servers via dhcp and it'll get what your router would get and you'll then see them

Answer (score 8):

I've done it both ways.

1. Your router typically caches the DNS entries it requests, and you only need to set it up once. Practically, after the first lookup it should be faster. Its also simpler, since you only need to set it up in one place. I don't use my ISP DNS servers so I always set it up here
2. no - your PC will simply ignore the router's dns server
3. Your router's ip address IIRC. I used to run a separate dns server *inside* my network at one point, and I simply used its ip address

Answer (score 3):

The OS always has the DNS server written in but it can be the router IP, and the router then goes to your ISP's.

Or the OS can point directly to a DNS server (your ISPs or somebody elses like Google offers a DNS server).

It should be faster to give your OS your ISPs or Google's DNS server, rather than your computer making a DNS request to your router and for your router to then contact a DNS server.

I can see my DNS servers in my router but if you can't then you can call your ISP and ask them. Or use Google's. `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`

Answer (score 1):

*I agree it should be a little faster, but I doubt that you notice.*

But it is easier to set it to the Router and then let the router release all the information to the client(s) ( DHCP ). If you have a second computer the next one is plug and Play.